# Can we perform mapping or do a lookup of string or KV pair in Varnish `sub vcl_recv`

Tags: haproxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to route the traffic/connections to backend director based on `url` parameters which are passed on incoming request.

Here is my current config

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "sto") {
        set req.backend_hint = endpoint1.backend();
    } 
}
```

Currently, above config does static mapping/check for `sto`. I would like to do a dynamic lookup from map/hash/KV file and do condition check with `url` contents.

Here is how I do it in `haproxy`

```
    use_backend %[path,map_sub(/etc/haproxy/GET.map)]
```

```
#>cat GET.map
# url paramter      backend location/name
/sgtier             get_backend1
/sto                get_backend2
```

Config file

```
vcl 4.0;
import directors;


backend sg_gw1 {
    .host = "1.8.4.4";
    .port = "1043";
}

backend tss_gw1 {
    .host = "1.8.13.2";
    .port = "8080";
}


sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "sto") {
       set req.backend_hint = sg_gw1;
    }
    elsif (req.url ~ "common") {
        set req.backend_hint = tss_gw1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic backends are supported in Varnish Enterprise. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/ for more information.

An open source alternative for dynamic backends can be found on https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-backend_dyn

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. I have created multiple backends (without director for now) I have create a map list which contains folder/bucket names. When user initiates the request to list objects from buckets/folder, I would like to compare request url containing bucket name and map file. If matched, send to respective backend. Else, send 503.

Comment: I have updated the config file in my post.

Comment: I would like to pass the map file in `sub vcl_recv` to do comparison and then set backend.